# Disable part of markup from compilation in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: html, angular, compilation, web-component

Is there a way to make part of markup ignored during Angular2 compilation? The issue is i have additional library that uses jQuery and `<template>` tags and because of Angular the `<template>` html tags are not present in DOM when the library tries to reach it with `$('template')` selector.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to inject needed HTML markup after containing container init. So i've made simple `$('container')[0].innerHtml = 'markup with <template></template>'` in one of my angular2 components in `ngOnInit` method.